# Convert Seq[(String,String)] to a query parameter string in Play! 2.0?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

Need to MD5 hash my query parameters for a Play! 2.0 web service request. Here's the skeleton method I'm putting together to handle the hashing:

```
  def API_SIG(params: Seq[(String,String)]) = {
    val hashParams = params.sortBy(_._1) :+ ("api_secret",API_SECRET)
    getMD5Hash(hashParams.toStringWhateverNativeMethod)
  }
```

That `Seq[(String,String)]` is the proper type for passing a sequence of query parameters to a Play! web service. For context:

```
  val requestParams = Seq() // nothing here, yet
  val finalParams = Seq(("api_key",API_KEY)) ++ requestParams
  val sigParams = requestParams :+ ("api_secret",API_SECRET)
  val signature = ("sig" -> API_SIG(params))
  val finalQueries = Seq(sigParam) ++ finalParams

  val request = 
    WS
    .url(requestUri)
    .withQueryString(finalQueries:_*)
```

A recap: I basically need to convert the `Seq[(String,String)]` to a query parameter string like `param=value&more=better&etc=keepsgoing`. Not sure if Play! has a native method for this or if anyone is aware of a simple way to do this. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no convenience method for this in Play 2.0. However, here's how they do it in their own source code:

```
params.map(pair => pair._1 + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(pair._2, "UTF-8")).mkString("&")
```

(changed variable names and stripped the unnecessary parts).

For more advanced options, you could also use [URLEncodedUtils](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URLEncodedUtils.html) in Apache HttpClient.

Comment: Ah thanks for finding that! I was scouring the source code but I was stuck searching ning's methods. Very helpful